# Как выбрать дату, которая не входит в диапазон других дат

Tags: mysql, sql

Ребят, помогите с запросом.
есть 2 таблицы.
1я таблица имеет дату начала dateStart и ID
2я ID и 4 поля дат. datePlanStart, dateFactStart, datePlanEnd, dateFactEnd

Как сделать запрос, который будет выдавать id у которого dateStart не будет пересекаться с датами из второй таблицы (не входит в промежуток datePlanStart, dateFactStart, datePlanEnd, dateFactEnd). При чем dateFact (начало и конец) будет приоритетней, чем datePlan. Т.е. это дата по факту (что произошло), а не запланировано, но даты факта могут быть еще не заполненны.
Пример

```
id  dateStart           
1   05.03.19            
2   01.03.19
3   02.03.19
4   28.02.19    

id  datePlanStart   dateFactStart   datePlanEnd dateFactEnd
1   12.02.19        11.02.19        02.03.19        04.03.19
2   14.02.19        12.02.19        08.03.19        01.03.19
1   12.02.19        11.02.19        02.03.19        null
2   14.02.19        null            27.02.19        null
```

должен найти id = 1, потому что (начало 11.02, а конец 04.03) и id=4 (dateStart>datePlanEnd), а id = 2 не выбирет, потому что и dateFactEnd = dateStart (must <=), id =3 не выберет т.к. datePlanEnd=dateStart

запрос работает, но наверное его можно улучшить как то

Заявка может длиться какое то время, поэтому dateStart я сделала requestStartDate и requestFinishDate

```
select v.ID
from tab1 v
left join tab2 t on t.ID=v.ID
where (@requestStartDate) between isnull(t.dateFactStart, t.datePlanStart) and isnull(t.dateFactEnd, t.datePlanEnd) and (@requestFinishDate) between isnull(t.dateFactStart, t.datePlanStart) and isnull(t.dateFactEnd, t.datePlanEnd)
or (@requestStartDate)<= isnull(t.dateFactStart, t.datePlanStart) and (@requestFinishDate)>=isnull(t.dateFactEnd, t.datePlanEnd) 
or (@requestStartDate)<= isnull(t.dateFactStart, t.datePlanStart) and (@requestFinishDate)between isnull(t.dateFactStart, t.datePlanStart) and isnull(t.dateFactEnd, t.datePlanEnd)
or (@requestStartDate) between isnull(t.dateFactStart, t.datePlanStart) and isnull(t.dateFactEnd, t.datePlanEnd) and (@requestFinishDate)>=isnull(t.dateFactEnd, t.datePlanEnd)"
```

Comment: "...Нужно сделать запрос.." - хм, мне тоже много чего нужно. Этот форум -  место, где не делают на халяву чужую работу, а помогают друг-другу.

Comment: Имеется ввиду как сделать. Это не работа, это не халява,.... это просто тренировки..мне надо понимать как работает...и я тренируюсь

Comment: "...и я тренируюсь" - похвально, но тогда нужно приложить в вопрос, что у Вас получилось (код, сделанный лично Вами, возможно не работающий) в процессе тренировки. После этого уже можно помочь и подсказать, что сделано не так.

Comment: добавила работающий запрос, если кто подскажет как его улучшить будет вообще WoW